# How to update multiple components (selectOneMenu) with depending objects relations?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, selectonemenu

i have the following (self-explanatory) entity-relation:

```
* Manufacturer
* Car    (Manufacturer.getCars())
* Tire   (Car.getTires())
```

**MyBean**

```
private List<Manufacturer> allManufacturers

private Manufacturer selectedManufacturer
private Car selectedCar
private Tire selectedTire
```

**xhtml**

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="manufacturerSel" value="#{myBean.selectedManufacturer}" converter="#{manufacturerConverter}">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="None" itemValue="#{null}" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{myBean.allManufacturers}" />
    <p:ajax update="carSel tireSel" />
</p:selectOneMenu>

<p:selectOneMenu id="carSel" value="#{myBean.selectedCar}" converter="#{carsConverter}" disabled="#{empty myBean.selectedManufacturer.cars}">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="None" itemValue="#{null}" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{myBean.selectedManufacturer.cars}"  />
    <p:ajax update="tireSel" />
</p:selectOneMenu>

<p:selectOneMenu id="tireSel" value="#{myBean.selectedTire}" converter="#{tiresConverter}" disabled="#{empty myBean.selectedCar.tires}">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="None" itemValue="#{null}" />                            
    <f:selectItems value="#{myBean.selectedCars.tires}"  />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

- the last two `p:selectOneMenu` should be updated  depending on the selection in the first one
- The last `p:selectOneMenu` with ID `tireSel` is not being updated correctly
- All the to-be-updated components are inside the same `NamingContainer`
- the `carSel` gets updated, but the values loaded in `tireSel` are strange (seem to be valid for the last request)
- i also tried `update="@form"` in `manufacturerSel`

**EDIT**
To show which EL Version is used:
Here´s an excerpt of my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.faces-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.12</version>
</dependency>    
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
    <artifactId>el-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You basically need to clear out the `selectedCar` value. You can use `<p:ajax listener>` for this.

```
<p:ajax listener="#{myBean.clearSelectedCar}" update="carSel tireSel" />
```

with

```
public void clearSelectedCar() {
    selectedCar = null; // You might want to clear selectedTire as well.
}
```

Otherwise the old selected value will still retain in the bean and the list of tires will still depend on that.

Comment: Hi BalusC, although using EL 2.2 i got `javax.el.ELException: Failed to parse the expression [#{myBean.setSelectedCar(null)}]`

Comment: What servletcontainer are you using? In the meanwhile just create a listener method the usual way which clears out the `selectedCar` property value.

Comment: I will try to add an bean-method and call id with `<p:ajax listener="#{myBean.resetSelectedCar}" ..>`

Comment: :-) Nice same thought. Using Tomcat 6.

Comment: Tomcat 6 doesn't ship with EL 2.2 out the box. What alternate EL implementation are you using?

Comment: added excerpt of my `pom.xml` to the post

Answer (score 2):

Normally, the PrimeFaces command button update works on the whole form. But sometimes we don't want to update the whole form, maybe we want to update a div with one id or multiple divs with the same class. It works with Primefaces and Spring Boot.

If you want to update the whole form just change the update attribute-

```
update="@form"
```

If you want to update a div within an ID

```
update="@(#divId)"
```

If you want to update multiple div or a single div using the class name-

```
update="@(.className)"
```

If you want to update multiple div or a single div using the class name-

```
update="@(.className1, .className2)"
```